# Change the default product image import directory

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-upload, product-import

Dears,

In magento 2.3.5, in order to add images within the product import csv, the images should be in:

```
var/import/images
```

While in the pass, the path was:

```
pub/media/images
```

My question is, is there anyway to change the default path from the new path to the old one ?
I tried many tricks, like writing the below

```
../../../pub/media/images
```

in the "Images File Directory" field, but it didn't work.

do you have any other suggestion ? it is critical to me to use pub/media.

On the other side, I think The default  path is taking from file:

```
/vendor/magento/module-import-export/etc/config.xml
```

So how can I override the file in my theme ?

Comment: Can you tried with url?
Like, yourdomain.com/pub/media/import/images/yourimagename.png

Comment: No, it is not accessible using the url

Answer (score 1):

You can override that value by adding that field in core_config_data

you can run below sql code for the same

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES ('default', '0', 'general/file/import_images_base_dir', 'pub/media');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However, I doubt I could do this trick, in fact, If I rerun the composer install or upgrade etc.. it will re-override the path.

Comment: config.xml is for default values and if you want to override the default values then you can add in core_config_data table like this